# What factors or Force decide elevation of wizards to a different color?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, gandalf

After the fight in Dwarvish ruins (Moria), Gandalf the grey fell and:

> rose as Gandalf the white.

What is the backstory of white wizards and grey ones?

Is there a order of wizards in this universe? What factors decide that the status of one wizard is to be elevated to a different color e.g. from Grey to white?

I'm new to LOTR universe so this may come across as a basic question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the backstory of white wizards and grey ones"?

Comment: You have a little reputation on this site, so by now you should know this isn't the way to ask a question. You should indicate that you've put at least a little effort into finding an answer.   Have you read any of the books?  That is the VERY FIRST thing I would recommend.

Comment: -1; There are a lot of questions popping up in the "related" sidebar that contain LOTR wizard history.  So, "rude" is a rather surprising term to use when asking people to summarize things that you don't want to waste a second to search for.

Comment: Your post contains multiple questions. One is about who decided that Gandalf would now be Gandalf the white? That is answered by the question Spencer linked. Your other question is if there is an order of Wizards. Yes there is, Saruman used to be head of that order. Third one is the back story of the different colors used to described the wizards. The last two are not answered in the linked question so I'd suggest first looking for already existing posts, if they don't, then ask new questions so that this doesn't get closed as too broad.

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate as the one you're asking in the title, but be aware that @Aegon is absolutely right: you're asking way too many questions here, most of which are answered elsewhere on the site. I encourage you to use the [handy search feature](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search) *before* asking; you'd be surprised what you can find

Answer (score -1):

You should read the [Silmarillion](http://www.tolkienlibrary.com/booksbytolkien/silmarillion/description.htm) by J.R.R. Tolkien to get accurate information. Also, there are other wizards with other colors like Radagast the Brown. Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe you could post the relevant bits from Silmarillion which answer this question?

Comment: Couldn't do it accurately since I've read it more than 10 years ago, If someone is interested they should look into it.

Comment: Once you get a rep of 10 (it's easy) you will be able to comment.

Comment: @Spencer 50 rep to comment; still easy, but a little harder than 10